# read XML from a webservice remove a child element based on the value of its attribute it and write it back to the

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Lets say The following is my xml input that I receive from my webservice using this code:

```
string url = txtURL.Text;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse rep = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(rep.GetResponseStream());
rep.Close();
```

now I have the following xml document in the "doc"

```
<note>
<parent_element>
<child_element attribute_1="1">
<inner_element> first Text </inner_element>
</child_element>
<child_element attribute_1="2">
<inner_element> second Text </inner_element>
</child_element>
</parent_element>
</note>
```

Now I want to remove the first child element based on its attribute value. So if the attribute value of the child element is "1" then I want to delete "child_element" and all of its child elements. so my final result should look like this:

```
<note>
<parent_element>
<child_element attribute_1="2">
<inner_element> second Text </inner_element>
</child_element>
</parent_element>
</note>
```

Once I have removed the element, I would write it back to the webservice. I know i am asking for a lot, but havent been able to figure it out so far.
I would include my code, but since I am a newbie to xml manipulation, i think that will be of no use (sad face). Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `doc.load(txtURL.Text)` is enough to load the XML from a remote location.

You can delete a node like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filename);

//Select node that needs to be deleted
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/note/parent_element/child_element[@attribute_1 = '1']");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

How you write all that back to your web application depends on what it is expecting. I will attach one example that POSTs a XML file against a RESTful web service

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(updateURL);

req.ContentType = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmldoc);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

Stream data = req.GetRequestStream();

data.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
data.Close();
```